# CSS background-color transition not working

Tags: css, background-color, css-transitions

using the following set of rules and style declarations

```
.tableRow.even, .tableRowNS.even, .odd   { background-color: #F2F2F2; }
.tableRow.odd, .tableRowNS.odd, .even   { background-color: white; }

.tableRow:hover,.noProject:hover,
.tableRow.even:hover, .tableRowNS.even:hover, .odd:hover,
.tableRow.odd:hover, .tableRowNS.odd:hover, .even:hover {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    transition: background-color .5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
    -o-transition: background-color .5s;
}
```

1. the mouseover color is working, but its not transitioning. am I approaching this incorrectly?
2. is there a problem with setting transition properties on multiple selectors like this?

Comment: What browser are you using? This jsfiddle using your css is working. http://jsfiddle.net/ZcXdt/

Comment: @keeyal, ah i just checked it out in chrome and you're right, it does work. thats funny. am I targeting firefox correctly? or is v10 actually too old for css3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add the firefox specific css3 transition property: `-moz-transition`.

after adding that, we have the following css. Now everything works fine.

```
.tableRow:hover,.noProject:hover,
.tableRow.even:hover, .tableRowNS.even:hover, .odd:hover,
.tableRow.odd:hover, .tableRowNS.odd:hover, .even:hover {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    transition: background-color .5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
    -o-transition: background-color .5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color .5s;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was going to post, so you can have the upvote :D

Comment: thanks! i wasn't sure if this was turning into a quiet post, so i decided to add the response just in case anyone stumbled upon it in the future :)